# Parse array with a array inside to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, post

I have array in my JS and I have to parse it to PHP:

```
var transfer_data = {
            cl_name : $("#free_1_1_title").val(),
            contact_name : $("#free_1_1_name").val(),
            contact_lastname : $("#free_1_1_lastname").val(),
            contact_email : $("#free_1_1_email_1").val(),
            cl_alley : $("#free_1_1_select_1").val(),
            cl_services : $("#free_1_1_select_2").val(),
            cl_tags : {
                1 : $("classified_tag_1").val(),
                2 : $("classified_tag_2").val(),
                3 : $("classified_tag_3").val(),
                4 : $("classified_tag_4").val(),
                5 : $("classified_tag_5").val()
            }
        };
```

and transfering:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "classifieds/add_new/addNewCl_1_1",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: transfer_data, 
            success: function(data) { 
                  console.log(data.response);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
```

and I want to receive it like that:

```
Array
(
    [cl_name] => value
    [contact_name] => value
    [contact_lastname] => value
    [contact_email] => value
    [cl_alley] => value
    [cl_services] => value
    [cl_tags] => array(1 => value, 2 => value...)
)
```

so how I should be supposed to do it? I tried to print receiving data with `print_r($_POST);`

and I got only

```
Array
(
    [cl_name] => value
    [contact_name] => value
    [contact_lastname] => value
    [contact_email] => value
    [cl_alley] => value
    [cl_services] => value
)
```

I'm missing my `cl_tags` with values

Comment: it could be like this,. cl_tags : [ ] not like cl_tags : { }

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I tried your code using several versions, and in all of them I got the desired result.

Comment: 1.10.2 at this moment

Comment: Odd, that's the same version I'm using. I created a test script that demonstrates it working: http://atli.advefir.com/test/test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change variable name in js

So working code are follow:

```
var data = {
    q:1, 
    'w[]': [1,3,4,5,7],
    'e[t1]': 1,
    'e[t2]': 2,
    'e[t3]': [1,2,3,4,5]
}
$.ajax({url:'/', type: 'POST', data: data});
```

In chrome debug we see follows:

```
q:1
w[]:1
w[]:3
w[]:4
w[]:5
w[]:7
e[t1]:1
e[t2]:2
e[t3][]:1
e[t3][]:2
e[t3][]:3
e[t3][]:4
e[t3][]:5
```

Comment: This really shouldn't be necessary. jQuery normally does this automatically for you. In fact, if you specify `w[]` as they key name, it would cause it to add an extra array around the element, effectively converting it to: `'w[][0]' : 'val'`. - I don't know what's up with the OPs code, but *normally*, this should not be done.

Comment: This is necessary in cases when you need to specify exact key in $_POST array. Example: `client[name]='Alex'` or `reminder[date]='date string'`

Comment: Nope, it should not be. If you pass a normal JSON object to a jQuery AJAX call, jQuery will take care of constructing the appropriate query string for you. Example: `var data={client:{name:'Alex'},reminder:{date:'date string'}}`

Comment: yes, this will be work. But my case are also can be. Couse it will converted to the query string in post and there will be notations from my case. Also in my case such notation of variables can be in input names also.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to to push array like that.

**JSON.stringify**:It converts js object to json object.

Do this.

```
step1.Create array/object.

step 2.JSON.stringify(array) to encode your array in JavaScript,

step 3.$array=json_decode($_POST['jsondata']);//in your php
```

And one more thing:

you cannot provide numeric key to a javascript object.

for example:

```
var object = {
 1:"wrong_way",
'1':true,
'alphabetic_key':"ideal";//boolean or number or string are valid as value.
}
```

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comment:

Its not the best of convention to use numbers as object keys.But if you do that the javascript engine will behind the scenes convert them in to strings.

But you have to be careful while accessing those object.

```
Object.'1';//valid
object.1;//invalid
object[1];//valid
```

Comment: It's perfectly legal to provide numbers as object keys. The parser will simply convert them to strings. `1:'val'` and `'1':'val'` are functionally equivalent. - The only problem is when you try to access the element. The `obj.1` syntax is invalid, it must be `obj['1']`, although `obj[1]` should also work.